# Leaflet.js consistent geoJSON data loading for performance

Tags: ajax, leaflet, geojson

I have to load geoJSON data from a postgres database which is quite heavy. The data is about 1MB whereas the rest of the code is about 35Kb.

What could be my best option to make the page quicker when loading?

I was thinking of loading the geoJSON through jQuery AJAX?

Any other suggestion or option? Maybe compression?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing now? Reading JSON via a service would of course be sufficient for 1MB of data. Compression is always better (enabling gzip is super easy to do). While this wouldn't be the most simple approach: I'd definitely recommend looking into a robust solution like GeoServer (geoserver.org) to serve up your data (it will connect to your postgres db) via a Web Feature Service (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/index.html). This will allow for a robust solution that would scale from 1MB of data to 100GB of data.

Comment: Am loading directly in my PHP script by querying the DB and writing the resulting json in the source of the page. As said I don't think it's a good solution. Had a look at geoserver and seems very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at TopoJSON which does miracles on GeoJSON size.

> TopoJSON is an extension of GeoJSON that encodes topology. Rather than representing geometries discretely, geometries in TopoJSON files are stitched together from shared line segments called arcs. TopoJSON eliminates redundancy, offering much more compact representations of geometry than with GeoJSON; typical TopoJSON files are 80% smaller than their GeoJSON equivalents.

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson

You can encode existing GeoJSON files using the commandline utility:

```
topojson -o output.json input.json
```

or in your case if possible use the serverside api:

```
var topojson = require("topojson");
var collection = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: […]}; // GeoJSON
var topology = topojson.topology({collection: collection}); // TopoJSON
```

While on the clientside you would unserialize TopoJSON using the clientside api:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
var geoJson = topojson.feature(topology, object);
```

Ideally one would cache the TopoJSON files instead of generating them on each request but that depends on your application.